# Optimal Trajectory for SLV in the last stage

Tags: guidance, pslv

I have developed an algorithm for SLV guidance using optimal control theory. I need a reference trajectory to verify my algorithm. The algorithm requires the initial position and velocity coordinates at last stage ignition; and the desired altitude, orbital velocity, flight path angle, inclination and longitude of the descending node. Also, the thrust and mass data for the SLV. Can anyone please tell me where can I find this data for any SLV so that I can verify my algorithm? I need this data from an authentic source so that I can cite the reference in my research paper.

Comment: Check Apollo by the Numbers to see if it has what you need. Page 256 has a lot of the numbers you seek for Apollo 17, but I haven't combed through the document to see if it has them all.  https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4029.pdf